# Вычитание матриц, но в excel

Tags: excel

Такой вопрос - можно ли реализовать что-то похожее на вычитание матриц в Excel?

У меня есть документ с 2-мя таблицами: верхняя - где производится расчёт, нижняя - с исходными данными. И я хочу реализовать такую схему - в ячейки "текущий ур." и "требуемый ур." табл. 1 вводить цифры, соответствующие числам из колонки "уровень" табл.2, и при вводе обоих чисел должна выводится разница соответствующих значений в колонках "ресурсы". Т.е., если я введу "текущий ур. 1" и "требуемый ур. 5", то в колонке "ресурсы 1" табл. 1 появится разница 2000-300. Также и в остальных колонках табл. 1. И если потом я введу "текущий ур. 5" и "требуемый ур. 7", то в колонке "ресурсы 1" табл. 1 появится разница 3000-2000.

[image: Таблицы]

Comment: В следующий раз показывайте не картинку, а ссылку на файл - так помогающим проще формулы писать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно создать формулу, которая пригодна для копирования во все нужные ячейки (AM11:AR14) без изменений. Для этого нужно использовать абсолютную адресацию столбцов "текущий ур." и "требуемый ур.", а так же отдельно пронумеровать столбцы в верхней таблице.

Дополнительно в 26-ую строку нужно добавить уровень 0.

Для нумерации столбцов нужно ввести числа от 2 до 7 в ячейки с AM$8 по AR$8 (число должно соответствовать номеру столбца в нижней таблице).

Формула для ввода в ячейку AM11:

```
=ВПР($AL11;$AJ$23$AP$36;AM$8;ЛОЖЬ)-ВПР($AK11;$AJ$23$AP$36;AM$8;ЛОЖЬ)
```

Эту формулу можно размножить по всем нужным ячейкам без изменения любым из этих способов:

1. Скопировать ячейку AM11, потом выделить AN11:AR11 и вставить. Выделить AM12:AR14 и вставить.
2. Выделить AM11 и размножить её вправо до AR11 включительно, потом имеющееся выделение размножить вниз до AR14 включительно.
3. Выделить AM11:AR14, начиная с AM11, нажать F2, потом Ctrl+Enter.

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понятно при чем здесь матрицы, но ваша задача решается, например, при помощи функции ВПР:

```
=ВПР(AL11;$AJ$27$AP$36;3;ЛОЖЬ)-ВПР(AK11;$AJ$27$AP$36;3;ЛОЖЬ)
```

Но вам придется, либо избавится от нолей в верхней табличке, либо добавить строчку уровня 0 в нижнюю, либо обернуть формулу в кучу проверок :)

**Источники:**

1. [Поиск значений с помощью функций ВПР, ИНДЕКС и ПОИСКПОЗ](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BF%D1%80-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7-68297403-7c3c-4150-9e3c-4d348188976b)
2. [Функция ВПР](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BF%D1%80-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Comment: Правильно говорить не "ложь", а "клади" :-)

Comment: AL4 и AK4 не годятся ни для какой ячейки. Для ячейки AM12, которая активна на картинке, нужно использовать AL12 и AK12.

Comment: @rotabor, спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 0):

Растянуть на всю таблицу:

```
=ВПР($AL11;$AJ$27:$AP$36;СТОЛБЕЦ(B1);)-ВПР($AK11;$AJ$27:$AP$36;СТОЛБЕЦ(B1);)
```

или

```
=ИНДЕКС($AJ$27:$AP$36;$AL11;СТОЛБЕЦ(B1))-ИНДЕКС($AJ$27:$AP$36;$AK11;СТОЛБЕЦ(B1))
```

Один из вариантов защиты от ошибки при `AL11 = 0` или `AK11 = 0`:

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ВПР(...)-ВПР(...);)
```